# javascript api to store authentication token on a third party domain

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication

We have our JS on third party website that authenticates with the server (cross domain). What is the best way to store Auth token.

1. We are thinking to create a Iframe and store token on that domain resource? Is this the best way? (Any examples on how to do this?)

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

kind regards,
Phani.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can be used cross-domain if you setup CORS accordingly on your server, I suggest this article for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials